# Categorization scheme of regression techniques

Tags: regression, machine-learning

There exist many techniques that can be used for regression task. Some are from statistics (e.g. generalized least squares) and some from machine learning (e.g. MLP), some are linear and some nonlinear, some are parametric and some nonparametric. Are there available any categorization schemes of regression techniques?

Comment: Are you seeking a taxonomy of predictive modeling methods for univariate $Y$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am exactly searching for.

Answer (score 2):

In the regression modeling realm here is a list.

1. Linear models with assumed normal residuals (OLS)
2. generalized linear models (e.g., gamma regression)
3. generalized additive models
4. transform-both-sides nonparametric additive regression (AVAS, ACE, canonical variates with splines)
5. quantile regression
6. other robust regression methods (see Venables & Ripley book)
7. semiparametric methods based on the ranks of $Y$ (Cox proportional odds model, proportional odds model, the larger family of cumulative probability models)
8. Penalized additive regression methods: lasso, quadratic penalty, elastic net

For # 7 predictions are things like log relative hazard or log relative odds.  The predictions can be transformed into predicted quantiles or means.

Comment: It looks good, but there are many techniques missing (especially machine learning), for example SVM, random forests, adaboost, MLP, MARS, ...

Comment: Yes that's why I prefaced it with 'regression modeling realm'.  But I've edited the list to include the additive regression methods used in machine learning.

Comment: Anyway, it should be clear from such categorization, which techniques are linear and nonlinear and which parametric and nonparametric.